# Why does plot behave differently for same but scaled data?

Tags: r, plot

Why does plot behave differently for different data, and how do you control it? My specific example today is getting different output with scaled and non-scaled data. For example

```
fit <- kmeans(mydata, 4)
plot(mydata, col = fit$cluster)
```

returns a nice 4x4 scatter matrix plot (mydata is 486x4) but

```
mydata <- scale(mydata)
fit <- kmeans(mydata, 4)
plot(mydata, col = fit$cluster)
```

returns a single plot showing variable 1 scatter plotted vs variable 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `scale()` returns a matrix rather than a data.frame. Just convert it back to a data.frame

```
mydata <- data.frame(scale(mydata))
```